# How can I dynamically change the css property using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change the css properties of a H1 tag dynamically using js or jquery. I mean if suppose I have a H1 tag with class fh and another H1 tag with class sh how can I change the font-size, color seperatly. I have make one but not working. How can I achive that?

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');

function handleUpdate() {
  const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || '';
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);
}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', handleUpdate));
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/hvk3k70z/1/)

UPDATE : how can I do this by dynamically sensing the h1 or p tags in my fiddle there is a range slider I want that when I click on h1 the current value ( properties ) of my h1 come in the range sliders respectively and I can edit them

Comment: $("h1").mousemove(function(){
 $(this).css("color","red");
});

Answer (score 0):

You can change css with like this in jQuery:

`$("css-selector").css("property", "value");`

You may use any css selector (# for ids, . for classes, etc).

**EDIT (considering your request):**

Take a look at this code. **It's not entirely working**, but it may give you an example of how to work with jQuery. You find css changes and events in it so try it out yourself.

```js
const inputs = $(".contorl input");
let active = $(".fh");

$("#fontsize").on("input", function(){
 active.css("font-size", $("#fontsize").css("font-size"));
});

$("#fontcolor").on("input", function(){
 active.css("color", $("#fontcolor").css("color"));
});

$(".fp").click(function(){
 $("#fontcolor").val($(".fp").css("color"));
  $("#fontsize").val($(".fp").css("font-size"));
  active = $(".fp");
});

$(".sh").click(function(){
 $("#fontcolor").val($(".sh").css("color"));
  $("#fontsize").val($(".sh").css("font-size"));
  active = $(".fh");
});

$(".fh").click(function(){
 $("#fontcolor").val($(".fh").css("color"));
  $("#fontsize").val($(".fh").css("font-size"));
  active = $(".fh");
});

$(".sp").click(function(){
 $("#fontcolor").val($(".sp").css("color"));
  $("#fontsize").val($(".sp").css("font-size"));
  active = $(".sp");
});
```

```css
.firstclass{ background-color:black;}
.secondclass {background-color:black;}
h1 {text-align:center;}
p {text-align:center;}

.fh {
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
}
.fp {
  color:white;
  font-size:15px;
}
.sh {
  color:red;
  font-size:35px;
}
.sp {
  color:red;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <label for="fontsize">Font size:</label>
  <br>
  <input id="fontsize" type="range" name="fs" min="10" max="200" value="10" data-sizing="px">
  <br>
  <label for="fontcolor">Font Color:</label>
  <br>
  <input id="fontcolor" type="range" name="fc" min="0" max="25" value="0" data-sizing="px">
  <br>
  <label for="base">Base Color:</label>
  <br>
  <input id="base" type="color" name="base" value="#95c6c6">
</div>

<div class="firstclass">
  <h1 class="fh">Title</h1>
  <p class="fp">This is some Para</p>
</div>

<div class="secondclass">
  <h1 class="sh">Title</h1>
  <p class="sp">This is some Para</p>
</div>

<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: well can u tell me how can I do this by dynamically sensing the h1 or p in my fiddle there is a range slider I want that when I click on h1 the current value ( properties ) of my h1 come in the range sliders respectively.